# PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! for DataFrame reader class

Tags: python, pandas

So I have been writing this class that will ingest two CSV files and write them to the same out path. Every time I try to run the class I get

*PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!*

I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Here is my class:

import pandas as pd

```
class twoCSVCombiner:

def _init_(self,fileOne,fileTwo,outPath):
    self.fileOne = fileOne
    self.fileTwo = fileTwo
    self.outPath = outPath

def reader(self,fileOne,fileTwo):
    fileOneDataframe = pd.DataFrame(fileOne)
    fileTwoDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(fileTwo)

def writer(self,outPath):
    self.outPath = open(self.outPath,'wb')
    fileOneOut = fileOneDataframe.to_csv(self.outPath,sep=',',header=True)
    fileTwoOut = fileTwoDataFrame.to_csv(self.outPath,sep=',',header=True)
```

Comment: Would be useful to know the *line* the error occurs on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use pd.DataFrame.from_csv() instead of just pd.DataFrame()? 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html

Comment: Thanks! Im such an idiot not to have added that. I actually went with pd.read_csv because it allows you set the dtypes. Thanks again!